# List the object properties of array list within an array list by AngularJS ng-repeat attribute

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a following JSON data

```
[Beds = [
    ElectricHospitalBed = [{name: 'Multifunctional electric hospital bed', code: 'IHC B/E 1001'},
        {name: 'Multifunctional electric hospital bed', code: 'IHC B/E 1002'},
        {name: 'Five functional electric hospital bed with ACP', code: 'IHC B/E 1003'},
        {name: 'Five functional electric hospital bed', code: 'IHC B/E 1004'},
        {name: 'Five functional electric hospital bed with ACP', code: 'IHC B/E 1005'},
        {name: 'Five functional electric hospital bed', code: 'IHC B/E 1006'},
        {name: 'Three functional electric hospital bed', code: 'IHC B/E 1007'},
        {name: 'Three functional electric hospital bed', code: 'IHC B/E 1008'},
        {name: 'Five functional electric hospital bed', code: 'IHC B/E 1009'}],
    Semi electric hospital bed = [],
    Manual hospital bed = [],
    Home care bed = [],
    Orthopedics bed = [],
    Childrens bed] = [],
Trollies = [Patient trolley = [],
    Stretcher = [],
    Nursing trolley [],
    Cambered trolley=[]]
]
```

I have to list all the names of products(given that each of the object is a product) by AngularJS ng-repeat attribute. Please advice.

Note: this JSON data is assigned to a variable named products in a controller called ProductsData.

Comment: data what you provided Its not in valid json format.can you correct and post the valid one

Comment: do mark as answered once solved (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it like `[Beds = [{},{}],[{},{}],[{},{}], Trolleys = [],[],[],]`

```
<div ng-repeat="c in products"> 
   <div ng-repeat="p in c"> 
   {{c.name}}
   </div>
</div>
```

c is categories in products ie beds, trolleys etc

p is item in each category,

and c.name should get you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

correct your json format in question.

anyways i changed and implimented in jsbin [here](http://jsbin.com/nubeyifuna/edit?html,js,output)